# Not sure how to distribute sections across pages of subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans, subreport

Please let me know if the explanation needs to be more clear.

I'm trying to create a report in Jaspersoft Studio composed of three sections: **customer info** (a JavaBean containing name, email, birthdate, etc.), **customer addresses** (a list of JavaBeans containing each of them street name, number, neighborhood, etc.) and **customer orders** (also a list of JavaBeans containing order number, date, a simple address description, order total, etc.)

From my understanding each of those sections would be a subreport and each one would be fed by a different JavaBean datasource.

I'm not sure how to distribute them across pages. For example, the first section (customer info) is small and could fit in one page together with the second section (customer addresses). But customer addresses may eventually grow beyond one page so perhaps it should be placed in a separate subreport (I'm assuming doing that creates separate pages for that section). I'm not familiar enough with JasperReports to look up a solution, in particular because I don't know how to add two datasources to the same report/page, only to a single report. This is why I'm considering one subreport per section, even though it is not very economic regarding the number of printed pages.

Also I'm not sure in which bands should I place the sections. I was able to place the first section in the *Title* and the second in the *Summary* band, but I'm not sure where to place the third section. Placing two sections in the same band (for example, in the *Title*) seems to cause the sections to overlap.

Any advice?

[image: Propposed report layout]

Comment: You can place all subreports at one band

Comment: Currently I'm placing the first two subreports in the _Title_ band and the last one in the _Summary_ band. The contents of the two subreports overlap if they grow too big (the _Stretch With Overflow_ option did not solve that) but I'm living with that as such event is not very probable. I've read that one can add more than one _Detail_ band in the same master report, would that be helpful in my case?